# What's the configuration the atmosphere for the servlet, primefaces 3.4 and glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: configuration, primefaces, glassfish-3, atmosphere, apache-tomee

My environment is Glassfish 3.1.2.2 (enable Comet), JDK 1.7.0_07, Atmosphere 1.0.0.RC1, JSF 2.1.10, and PrimeFaces 3.4 on Windows 7.

I am trying out the Counter example ([primefaces 3.4 counter](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/push/counter.jsf))
I followed the steps for manual [PF3.4](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf) and I enabled Comet support in my domain.

My servlet configuration...

```
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>org.atmosphere.websocket.maxTextMessageSize</param-name>
         <param-value>0</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache</param-value>
        </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But this example, not works, because haven't comunication between the browsers.
Also, I have the following warnings

```
WARNING: GRIZZLY0024: Terminate process interrupted.

WARNING: SelectorFactory. Can not create a selector
```

Anyone, **another configuration for atmosphere would lack?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, there is not a known, working configuration or test case demonstrating that PrimeFaces Push works on Glassfish 3.1.2.2. This has been mentioned, discussed, and realized/experienced by myself and others in the PrimeFaces community.

Please see the following PrimeFaces Push forum topic, where this was discussed; at the end of the conversation, you will see that I migrated to TomEE Plus (tomcat7/OpenEJB), and Atmosphere is working flawlessly, like a champ...finally!

[Glassfish 3.1.2.2](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=25577)

Also, keep your eyes on topics discussed in [PrimeFaces Push](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewforum.php?f=10) community forum, as someone might reach/find success using PrimeFaces Push with/on Glassfish 3.1.2.2.

One more thing, I am very much the loyal type, and I wanted to stay with Glassfish 'for life', but I really wanted to use PrimeFaces Push (or Atmosphere), and when I tried and tried, and was not able to reach success with Glassfish, 'and' since I was ready to migrate from JSF maanaged beans to CDI managed beans, and seen/heard that Glassfish/Weld has issues with CDI managed beans, I decided to migrate from Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Tomcat/TomEE Plus. Now, I'm talking with TomEE/OpenEJB committers, trying to improve the performance of my app to run in TomEE/OpenEJB container.

I only had one issue with PrimeFaces Push on TomEE Plus container, which has already been resolved (yesterday). See/click below.

[How can I conditionally render .js file in h:head, if file was not rendered after Full Page Refresh (FPR)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532172/how-can-i-conditionally-render-js-file-in-hhead-if-file-was-not-rendered-afte)

I am using the PrimeFaces Push FacesMessage (example) in my app. On Glassfish 3.1.2.2, I developed a similar implementation via p:poll, but now, I finally have PrimeFaces Push FacesMessage implementation working great via TomEE Plus. :)

Hope this helps (you to migrate from Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to TomEE or tomcat as well).